# How do I use TridentGoalSeek on an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array whose first element is always 1.
Each successive element is calculated by multiplying the previous element by a factor.
The array will never have more than 20 elements.
The sum of all elements in this array, when subtracted from another user defined value gives a balance/remainder.
I wish to bring this number to as close to zero by changing the "factor" that is used to create successive elements.
I am  using Visual Studio for 1 week now. Im a noob on all fronts. Coding, Visual Studio, GoalSeek  is the very first Package that I have installed and this is my first Post on Stack Overflow.
Here is code I used to create my initial array:

```
static void CalcTurns()
{
    int i = 1;

    do {
        Turn[i] = Turn[i - 1] * rate;
        Player1.TotalPlayed += Turn[i];

        Player1.Balance = Player1.Capital - Player1.TotalPlayed;
        i++;
    } while (Player1.TotalPlayed + Turn[i - 1] * rate < Player1.Capital);
}
```

Solved.
I thought about @The Generals comment and tried to solve with a method. Kept original method to compare differences. I chose a minute (minewt) value to increment the factor for greater precision.

```
static void GoalSeek()
{
    while (Player1.Balance > 1) {
        dynamicRate += 0.000001f;
        int i = 1;
        
        do {
            Turn[i] = Turn[i - 1] * dynamicRate;
            Player1.TotalPlayed += Turn[i];

            Player1.Balance = Player1.Capital - Player1.TotalPlayed;
            i++;
        } while (Player1.TotalPlayed + Turn[i - 1] * dynamicRate < Player1.Capital);
    }
}
```

Not Solved. Not Solved.

Ok, So I have partially solved it using recursion, however the larger the user input a "Stack OverFlow" error is generated. smaller values work.

```cs
static void CalcTurns(decimal factor, float _balance, float _totalPlayed)
{
    int i = 1;
    while (_totalPlayed + (Turn[i-1] * (float)factor) < Player1.Capital)
    {
        Turn[i] = Turn[i - 1] * (float)factor ;
        _totalPlayed += Turn[i];
        _balance = Player1.Capital - _totalPlayed;

        Player1.Turns++;
        
        
        Player1.Balance = _balance;
        Player1.TotalPlayed = _totalPlayed;
        i++;
    }
    
    if (_balance > 0.1)
    {
        dynamicRate += 0.0001m;
        CalcTurns(dynamicRate , Player1.Capital - minBet , minBet);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a raw math problem, if you get the right solve it would be efficient and easy to write the solution in any language. Try the math stack exchange site

Comment: Thanks. Will do. Have to wait 40 minutes though.

Comment: why not use a stack or queue?  it is more safe.  With an array you could hit an boundary error if you logic is not correct